# Mailing ATU reports

Tags: selenium

I have implemented ATU reports successfully in my project using maven, how ever Index.html ATU report will be generated at the @Aftersuite completion method. But in the @Aftersuite method I have mail code which sends the reports zip file to the users including the index.html. By that time Index.html is not generated. Does anyone have ideas to generate the ATu reports index.html before after suite methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use surefire maven plugin or failsafe maven plugin to set the running phase of your test (by default it will be in the test phase if noting being set). Then if you use maven postman plugin you can set the the phase for that also. And if you use java mail then you can trigger your class from maven exec plugin.